# Add References to External Database in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2013

I need to include a Stored Procedure in Visual Studio 2013 which references another Database which is not part of the solution.  I only refer to a very small portion of the external database which is itself big and complicated.

I know I need to add a reference to it so that I don't get warnings when referring to objects within the external database from within the Stored Procedure.

Adding that Database to a this or another Solution is not an option as its not part of our solution and importing that creates a whole variety of other issues.

I can see in older versions of Visual Studio that I need to create a schema file using VSDBCMD but this has been replaced by SQLPackage, but I can't see how to access that and whether it will need the external database anyway.

I've been going round in circles on this, so some pointers would be warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I realize I am late to the party on this but perhaps it will still be useful to someone:  You don't mention if this is a c# project or a database project.

I'll assume database as I not sure how you'd get errors otherwise on the internals of an SP.

The only way I know of to remove errors on cross-database references is to add the other database as a project in the database solution, add a database reference to the project with the sp, and then instead of using Database.schema.table syntax in the sp change it (in the database project) to [$(database)].schema.table

Alternately, a DACPAC can be created on the referenced database and used instead of referencing the database in an added project.

I'm new to this stuff myself, but I work with a lot of database cross-references in my sps so I am working through how to address this in database projects